# Table not on place

Tags: tables

My Problem ist that I've two tables which should be in the same subsection and I also think I wrote the code right

Here is the main Code

```
\section{example}
\input{Textparts/Lighting/Momentary1.tex}
\newpage
    \input{Textparts/Lighting/Momentary2.tex}
```

and Momentary 1 and Momentary 2 has each one table inside but the problem is that the second table gets displayed 3 subsection further down

Comment: This table probably haven't enough place on page where start third subsection.

Comment: Use `\clearpage` not `\newpage`. Floats will never float past a `\clearpage`.

Answer (score 1):

Latex places tables were it thinks they will best fit.

You can use the placement options to overwrite this H places the table exactly where you specified (needs the float package). there are also options for bottom/top of page and as close as possible to where you specified it.

Without the actual table code it is difficult to say more.

Comment: I disagree about `H`. If the table (or picture) is to big to be placed immediately after text, where you wish to have, it will be moved to the next page and left empty place on previous page.  So, use of H is solution, which result is not beautiful ...

Comment: Do you have an alternative? From the sounds of it the problem is that they do not like the "nice" placement. h may be another solution, it places it as close possible but allows latex to maintain some formatting.